# The Weil numbers and modulus of an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology

I have an ignorant question about elliptic curves which I'll be slightly imprecise about. If I have an elliptic curve $X$ defined over $\mathbb Z$, I can base change to $\mathbb C$, and then $X(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb C$ by the lattice generated by $1, \tau$ for some $\tau \in \mathbb C$.

I can also base change to a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, and then the Frobenius operator on $H^1 (X( \bar {\mathbb{F} }_q), \bar {\mathbb{Q} }_l)$ has eigenvalues $\sigma, \bar \sigma$.

> Q: Is there any relationship between $\sigma, \bar \sigma$, and $\tau$?

(I may have glossed over some things, like fixing an <strike>identification</strike> embedding of $\bar {\mathbb Q}$ into $\mathbb C$, or requiring $X(\mathbb F_q)$ to be smooth, or something else.)

Comment: Probably you mean "fixing an identification of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ with a subfield of $\mathbb C$," rather than with $\mathbb C$ itself.

Comment: Hmm, I did indeed.

Comment: You might enjoy reading about the Igusa-Manin theorem.

Comment: What is intrinsic is not $\tau \in \mathbf{C}$ but $\tau \in \mathbf{C}/{\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z}) \simeq \mathbf{C}$ (isomorphism by $j$), and the pair $\sigma, \overline{\sigma}$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius $T^2 - a_q T + q$, where $a_q = q+1 - \#X(\mathbf{F}_q)$.  At a good prime the reduction of $j(X)$ is the $j$-invariant of the reduction, so your question could be seen as entirely about elliptic curves $E$ over finite fields $k$: what is the relationship between $j(E) \in k$ and $\#E(k)$? Yet a quadratic twist can change $\#E(k)$ but not $j(E)$.

Comment: @nfdc23 So you mean there's different $E$ that have the same $j(E)$ but not $\# E$? Does this a-priori mean that these aren't related? It seems possible that some function of $\# E$ might remain constant even if $\# E$ changes.

Also, is there a reference for the Igusa-Manin theorem?

Comment: If $j(E)=j(E')$, then $E$ and $E'$ are isomorphic over an algebraic closure of their field of definition, but not necessarily over their field of definition. This is the whole subject of "twists". See any intro text on elliptic curves. For finite fields of characteristic $p\ge5$, a curve $E$ has a unique quadratic twist, and the traces of Frobenius for the two curves are negatives of each other.

Comment: PS in some sense there are no elliptic curves defined over Z ;-)

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm asking is that there's an algebra defined using elliptic curves over finite fields that's very interesting from the point of view of representation theory, algebraic combinatorics, knot theory, etc. (the Hall algebra of $Coh(X)$). Burban and Schiffmann showed that the structure constants of this algebra are (Laurent) polynomials in $\sigma, \bar \sigma$. I was trying to get some idea of what this means, but so far in my (mathematical) life I've mostly done representation theory over $\mathbb C$, hence the ignorance.

Answer (score 13):

If $E$ does not have CM, then $\tau$ will be transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, so it's hard to imagine  a relation with the eigenvalues of Frobenius, which are integers in an imaginary quadratic field. However, if $E$ does have CM, then $\text{End}(E)\otimes\mathbb Q\cong\mathbb Q(\tau)$, and Frobenius lifts to an endomorphism of $E$ that is in the ring of integers of this field, so if you choose the right value for $\tau$, then they can be very closely related. If you want more details, read any standard treatment on complex multiplication and elliptic curves.